# Next JS stuck fetching the same page over and over again

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a next JS project where I need to fetch some data and display it.
The application fetches data from an API and displays it using various components. However, I'm encountering issues. My guess is it has to do with caching, but im not sure. Im using "use client" at the top of the file that contains the component and im fetching data asynchronously. Here's the code snippet for the main Home component:

```
"use client";
import NavigationPanel, {
    TopBarNav,
} from "./components/Navigation/navigationpanel";
import BannerSlider from "./components/banner-slider";
import SportsContent from "./components/sports-content";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getSoccerFeaturedMatches } from "@/api";

export const Home = ({ params }: any) => {

    const [pregameodds, setPregameodds] = useState([]);
    const [soccerodds, setSoccerodds] = useState([]);
    const [soccerleagues, setSoccerleagues] = useState([]);
    const [tennisodds, setTennisodds] = useState([]);
    const [tennisleagues, setTennisleagues] = useState([]);
    const [cricketodds, setCricketodds] = useState([]);
    const [cricketleagues, setCricketleagues] = useState([]);

    const [basketballodds, setBasketballodds] = useState([]);
    const [basketballleagues, setBasketballleagues] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFeaturedMatches = async () => {
            try {
                const matches = await getSoccerFeaturedMatches();
                setPregameodds(matches); // Update the state with fetched data
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching featured matches:", error);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    const banners = [
        {
            image: "/sportbanner1.jpeg",
        },
        {
            image: "/sportbanner2.jpeg",
        },
        {
            image: "/sportbanner3.jpeg",
        },
        {
            image: "/sportbanner4.jpeg",
        },
        {
            image: "/sportbanner5.jpeg",
        },
        {
            image: "/sportbanner6.jpeg",
        },
    ];
    return (
        <div className="flex h-[calc(100vh_-_105px)] max-w-[1450px] mx-auto">
            <div className="w-[255px] hidden md:flex overflow-auto h-[100%]">
                <NavigationPanel />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 bg-[#282828] overflow-auto h-[100%] text-base">
                <TopBarNav />
                <BannerSlider banners={banners} />
                <SportsContent
                    odds={pregameodds}
                    soccerodds={soccerodds}
                    soccerleagues={soccerleagues}
                    tennisodds={tennisodds}
                    tennisleagues={tennisleagues}
                    basketballodds={basketballodds}
                    basketballleagues={basketballleagues}
                    cricketodds={cricketodds}
                    cricketleagues={cricketleagues}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

When switching to the network tab on inspect element i see this:
https://gyazo.com/e8d6b8ca3ee034387997b56e3c44a804

This is my next version:13.4.2
This is my react version:18.2.0

Comment: I don't really see a reason to make this component client side. Make a server side component out of it.

Comment: @FabioNettis I don't think thats a solution. It seems more of an issue to me with the client side components and maybe someone else can have similar issue too.

Comment: It is not a solution, henceforth he comment and not an answer. I still recommend not uselessly using client components.